# Simple link_to_remote function - can't get it to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

After utilizing the great trial and error for over an hour along with dozens of tutorials and blogs posting examples, I still cannot get the simple ajax functionality to work.  Here is what is in my partial:

```
<span id="friend">
  <%= link_to_remote image_submit_tag("/images/add_as_friend.gif"), :url => {:controller => 'friends', :action => 'add', :id => id} %>
</span>
```

This is what is in my controller:

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  def add
    unless params[:id].nil?
      Friend.create(:user_id => @current_user.id, :friend_id => params[:id], :friend_type => 2)
    end
  end
end
```

This is what is in my add.rjs file:

```
page.replace_html 'friend', "A request to be friends with this player has been sent."
```

The image for the link comes up fine.  When I click on it, however, nothing happens. I've checked the database and nothing is going on.  I must be missing something, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you are using `image_submit_tag` rather than `image_tag` for the content of your link. `image_submit_tag` is for submitting forms so will have its own onclick behaviour which may override the onclick behaviour that will be added as part of the `link_to_remote` functionality.

I would try:

```
<%= link_to_remote image_tag("/images/add_as_friend.gif"), 
    :url => {:controller => 'friends', :action => 'add', :id => id} %>
```

Comment: In addition to this, I did not render anything from the action.  I added the line-   render :partial => 'friend' and now it's workgin smoothly.  Thanks!